# How to exec sql within visual C# express (ddl file)?

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework

I've installed Visual C# express 2010 to try to use entity framework.
I've added an entity data model file and followed the wizard and finally create a local database file.
I've added entity and visual C# express generates me a DDL file.

But how can I execute this sql file within visual C# express ?

(if possible, I would like to avoid installing sql server management studio)

Thanks for your answer.
Best regards

Comment: You need to have **some tool** installed to execute the .SQL script - doesn't have to be Mgmt Studio, but something similar. Visual Studio itself cannot do the job. Or you can use the command-line `SQLCMD` tool to run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
It seems I need to use mandatory sql server management studio : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593